# How could I translate VLC into Norwegian (bokmaal)?

Tags: application-development, vlc, translation

I want to contribute to the fabulous Ubuntu world, but am a novice in technology and programming.

But on the contrary, I am quite strong within my language Norwegian (bokmaal).
(Norway is bilingual).

And I have seen that VLC player is translated into Norwegian (nynorsk) only, leaving the bokmaal language unavailable for this app.

Who can I talk to to translate VLC player to `lang=nb`? I would love to do this job.

Answer (score 1):

From `man vlc` I have found this [documentation link](http://www.videolan.org/doc/) (at the end of the man page). There I've looked for "Contribute" and finally landed on the [translation page](http://www.videolan.org/developers/i18n/). It refers to a [howto](http://www.videolan.org/developers/i18n/vlc-howto.html) which should be followed to translate into a new language.

However, it seems to me that there is already a maintainer for "Norwegian Bokmål". You might want to contact him first.

Comment: Updated VLC and found it now is a mix of both our languages..
So I guess it is already a work in progress. That's good and I'll see whereelse I can contribute.